# nginx and php7.2-fpm only working on IP Adress

Tags: php, nginx

Php Scripts on my Nginx / php7.2-fpm only working with the default config and the IP Adress not with Domain Names or subdomains...

My Configs:

Default Config

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

}
```

My Domain Config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/fluke667/html/web.mydomain.com/web;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name web.mydomain.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;
        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    #default_type application/octet-stream;
    default_type        text/html;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Without that subdomain and with IP it works in /var/www/html
Dont know why, can any1 Help me?

Comment: So in the `default.conf` you have it `fastcgi_pass` to the `php7.2-fpm.sock` but the other you have it set up like a static website thus it only works when it hits via the IP

Answer (score 0):

Using `wordpress` codex for `nginx` as an example

```
    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
```

Which means for any request in this `server` block the first location block most likely will run. It will first `try` to find a static file, then try to look for a directory with that request path, then finally send it to `index.php`. When sent to the `index.php` the second location block of `location ~ \.php$` will run which will send all requests with the `php` file extension to the `php7.2-fpm.sock`

You currently have 2 `server` blocks. One in `Default Config` and one in `My Domain Config`. You have `server_name web.mydomain.com;` in your custom conf which means any requests to that host will be answered by that `server` block. Any other host will be handled by the `Default Config` which includes by IP.